# Missing countries in Here Maps

Tags: maps, here

I was about to download the maps for my next trip and noticed several countries are not listed to be downloaded

- South Korea
- Mongolia
- Kyrgyzstan
- Tajikistan
- Uzbekistan
- Turkmenistan

There are more missing in Asia, but these are the ones I care about right now.

Is there a reason for this? Any way to get them anyways?

WP 8.1 latest Here Maps

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately some countries are not available. I don't know any official list, but if the needed country is not listed in the download section there is no way to get it. :/